# Any method to make the image in imageSwitcher can pinch zoom pan?

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery, pinchzoom, imageswitcher

i was using ImageSwitcher And Gallery Demo Activity.
But the demo image cannot be zoom. any method can make the ImageSwitcher zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a method in the default ImageView which enables pinch to zoom. I would look into using a 3rd party library to save you the work of creating one yourself. I would recommend [Gesture ImageView](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview).

Comment: I am not too familiar with ImageSwitcher but you can try looking at the suggestion from another question asked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950331/389141